# помогите с распаковкой python

Tags: python

как это распаковать? [('red',)]

из этого [('red',)] в это red

Comment: `(b,), = [('red',)]`

Answer (score 5):

```py
a = [('red', 'blue'), ('red', 'blue'),]

(b, *_), *_ = a or ((None,),)
print(b)
```

> Будет проблема только если первый кортеж окажется пустым

А конкретно для Вашего примера, как я уже написал в комментарии

```
(b,), = [('red',)]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!

Comment: @malaznal, если вам помог этот ответ, отметьте его как "принятый" (серая галочка слева).